# How do I install libsuinput on Raspberry Pi 10 (Buster)

Tags: linux-kernel, configure, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm working on a project that requires libsuinput available here

https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/libsuinput

I've downloaded it but when I follow the instructions in the readme

*Just run the following commands:*

```
./configure && make && make install
```

I get the following error

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Instructions couldn't be simpler but its just not working. Am I missing something or is the module not compatible with the latest version of Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `./autogen.sh` first - it will call autoreconf that will create `configure` script.

If you get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/libsuinput $ ./autogen.sh
aclocal: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory
configure.ac:9: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

install libtool:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libtool
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that but I get an error 'aclocal: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory

Comment: *an error* doesn't say much, you have to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise enter would submit

Comment: I've created the m4 directory and tried again and now get error 'configure.ac:9: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

Comment: Don't worry about the warning and install libtool: `sudo apt-get -y install libtool`